# How to find which thread currently owns the lock in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a synchronized method in a singleton class which is called by many threads simultaneously. Is there any java API available to check which thread is currently owning the lock ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps print out `Thread.currentThread()` in your synchronized method.

Comment: I think am not very precise with my question. One of the threads is blocked while attempting to call a synchronized method. So am planning to run a timer task that can call some java API which helps me know which thread is owning that lock. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. But even if you were to achieve it, what would you do with the thread? You can't stop it anyway unless it comes out of the execution by itself or times out.

Answer (score 4):

Precise answer given by `erickson` [[***here***]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561/programmatically-determine-which-java-thread-holds-a-lock)

> **Question:**  Programmatically determine which Java
> thread holds a lock ?

---

> **Answer :**
>
> You can only tell whether the current
> thread holds a normal lock
> (Thread.holdsLock(Object)). You can't
> get a reference to the thread that has
> the lock without native code.
>
> However, if you're doing anything
> complicated with threading, you
> probably want to familiarize yourself
> with the java.util.concurrent
> packages. The ReentrantLock does allow
> you to get its owner (but its a
> protected method, so you'd have to
> extend this). Depending on your
> application, it may well be that by
> using the concurrency packages, you'll
> find that you don't need to get the
> lock's owner after all.
>
> There are non-programmatic methods to
> find the lock owners, such as
> signaling the JVM to issue a thread
> dump to stderr, that are useful to
> determine the cause of deadlocks.

By the way,please have a look at the following link. It provides all information about thread related aspects :

- [JVM's ThreadMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html)

Answer (score 2):

The jvm [ThreadMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) gives you access to all kinds of thread related info, including which threads own which locks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking into debugging the software to figure out which thread is causing the blocking and which one being blocked, I'd suggest simply getting a thread dump of the live situation. I wouldn't use this kind of logic as part of normal program flow.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/