# How to find out whether another thread is wait()ing?

Tags: java

I notice there is no isWaiting() method. Is it possible to test whether any thread is blocked wait()ing on a specific object? Given a Thread object, is it possible to find which object, if any, that Thread is wait()ing on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, for the waiting state try `thread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING || thread.getState() == TIMED_WAITING`.

As for the object the thread waits for, I'm not sure but I doubt you could get the object the thread is wating for without native code. The otherway round, i.e. getting the thread which holds a lock on a given object, also seems to be impossible with pure Java (see here: [Programmatically determine which Java thread holds a lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561/programmatically-determine-which-java-thread-holds-a-lock)).

Answer (score 0):

The basic concurrent methods may not suffice your needs. You may want to try java.util.concurrent package. One of the example classes that can solve your problem is [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).  Here is the complete [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) on threads.

Comment: I guess you are sorta-kinda answering the question, since this lock contains a getOwner() method.