# Thread.start() method holds lock on which object?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have a doubt, if `Thread.start()` method is `synchronized` then it must require a lock on monitor of some object.

How to check this and get reference to that object?

```
public class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadDemo().start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("Parent thread :" + currentThread());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(currentThread() + " Child thread holding lock : " + currentThread().holdsLock(this));
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
Parent thread : Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] Child thread holding lock : false
Parent thread : Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] Child thread holding lock : false
Parent thread : Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] Child thread holding lock : false
```

Expected:

Since I am checking lock on current object that should return `true` instead of `false`.

Please correct me if I missed anything.

In the suggested post it shows that we can check if a thread holds lock on some object by method Thread.holdsLock(Object) where we have reference of Object prior to check. But I want to make it confirm if start() method holds lock on some object. If yes then which one it would be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically determine which Java thread holds a lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561/programmatically-determine-which-java-thread-holds-a-lock)

Comment: What you seem to be missing is that run() is executed on a different thread, that was started before, when start() was executed on the main thread. start() has already returned and released the lock when run() is being executed.

Comment: In the suggested post it shows that we can check if a thread holds lock on some object by method Thread.holdsLock(Object) where we have reference of Object prior to check. But I want to make it confirm if start() method holds lock on some object. If yes then which one it would be?

Comment: You don't need any experiment for this. The start() method is synchronized. So when it's executed, it holds the lock on the Thread object. Once it returns, it releases the lock. And some time later, run() is being executed.

Comment: @michalk but Thread.start() method is synchronized and it is getting called inside main thread so it must acquire lock. Is it?

Comment: @NitinSinghal you seem to think that the sequence is 1. start() starts executing, 2. run() starts executing, 3. run() ends its execution, 4, start() ends its execution. That is not the sequence. The sequence is 1. start() starts executing, 2. starts() ends its execution, 3. run() starts its execution, 4; run() ends its execution. So, once again, when run() is executed, the lock that was obtained by start() has been released.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your valuable explanation with describing sequence of execution. Now I got what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is unreasonable. I would expect that the purpose of the lock is to give the newly-created thread the ability to see all the information the thread that called `start` provides it such as what function to call on what object. By the time you get to `run`, the newly-created thread has had to access that information, so the creating thread should be expected to have released the lock by that point.

Comment: I think you're missing the part where the OP thinks that `run()` is called from within the `start()` call.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The OP uses the term "Child thread" in the example code, so the OP must understand that `run` is called in a separate thread. It seems that what the OP is missing is that the newly-created thread probably needs to acquire that lock to get to `run`.

Comment: Have a look at how the OP responded to JB Nizet's comment. The OP apparently was reasoning under the misapprehension that a call to `t.start()` could not return before the thread's `run()` method returned. I've seen more than a few questions on this site (and answers too!) in which people use phrases like "child thread," confident that they know what they are talking about, when they actually have no clue.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That's amazing. I can't imagine what the OP thought the purpose of a thread was if you had to wait for it to finish before the thread that created it could continue. In any event, I think this answer is more useful to other people as is given that the OP's issue is already understood and not likely to be the issue of others who read/find this question.